# How can I change the main heading of the plot of rasterbrick?

Tags: r, raster

I have a rasterbrick comprising of six layers

`class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 47, 89, 4183, 6  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : 60.75, 105.25, 15.75, 39.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : in memory
names       :

min values  :         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0 
max values  :  22.84560,   9.63050,  28.18740,  12.90590,  51.66701,  319.83840`

But when I plot the sixth variable, it shows the main heading as VegCX2X0.7, but I want to change it to "Aboveground Biomass Carbon", so I do the following basic code :

`plot(try3,6,  col=mycol, main=" Aboveground Biomass", legend.args=list(text='Aboveground Carbon Biomass(MgC/ha)', side=4, font=2, line=2.5, cex=0.8))`

But the new heading doesnt show up, in fact no heading is not shown. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Always try to come up with a reproducible example to get the best answer (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)). Suppose this is your raster `brick`:

```
library(raster)

#reproducible example
set.seed(987)

# setting up list pf raster stacks
r1 <- raster(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, res = 0.5, xmn = -1.5, xmx = 1.5, ymn = -1.5, ymx = 1.5, vals = runif(36, 1, 5))
r.brk <- brick(lapply(1:6, function(i) setValues(r1,runif(ncell(r1)))))
names(r.brk) <- c("VegC",     "LittC",    "SoilfC",    "SoilsC",     "Total", "VegCX2X0.7")
```

you can change the name of rasters by:

```
names(r.brk) <- c("n1",     "n2",    "n3",    "n4",     "n5", "Aboveground Biomass")
plot(r.brk) #plot them in a group by their name as main title
```

As you have limitations for choosing names, you can also change the main while plotting them as a group:

```
plot(r.brk, main=c("n1",     "n2",    "n3",    "n4",     "n5", "Aboveground Biomass Carbon"))
```

or you can change the main plot title while plotting any of them separately as below:

```
plot(r.brk$Aboveground.Biomass, main="Aboveground Biomass Carbon")
```